# ASP.net How to Center Exported image in Excel

Tags: asp.net, excel, center

I have to export some images to excel, To center the images I use a table and colspan=4 to merge four columns of excel file,

when I write a text to excel file it is easily get centered, but for image I tried every possible scenarios, like img algin="center" or  
and even put it inside a table and , but the result is the same.

any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that images are not bounded to the cell grid in Excel, they float.
You can't center them even using the Excel interface.